# How to combine awk and if in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, awk, pipe

I have 2 text file named as newport and panel port shown below. My awk command combines two files according to their common line to port.txt. I want also not common lines in the new file described in mypurpose. I couldn't combine awk and if or another |awk command.

```
awk -F' ' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1,a[$1]}' newport.txt panelport.txt > port.txt
```

newport

```
LTECD11L 444
```

panelport

```
ENODEB1513L #
ENODEB1521L #
ENODEB1522L #
ENODEB1532L #
ENODEB1533L #
LTECD11L #
LTECD12L #
LTECD14L #
L650112L #
LTEG211L_1 #
LTEG212L_1 #
NodeB1213L #
NodeB1214L #
ENODEB1612L #
ENODEB1614L #
ENODEB1617L #
NodeB1113L #
NodeB1114L #
BB663011L #
BB663012L #
```

port

```
ENODEB1513L 
ENODEB1521L 
ENODEB1522L 
ENODEB1532L 
ENODEB1533L 
LTECD11L 444
LTECD12L 
LTECD14L 
L650112L 
LTEG211L_1 
LTEG212L_1 
NodeB1213L 
NodeB1214L 
ENODEB1612L 
ENODEB1614L 
ENODEB1617L 
NodeB1113L 
NodeB1114L 
BB663011L 
BB663012L
```

mypurpose

```
ENODEB1513L #
ENODEB1521L #
ENODEB1522L #
ENODEB1532L #
ENODEB1533L #
LTECD11L 444
LTECD12L #
LTECD14L #
L650112L #
LTEG211L_1 #
LTEG212L_1 #
NodeB1213L #
NodeB1214L #
ENODEB1612L #
ENODEB1614L #
ENODEB1617L #
NodeB1113L #
NodeB1114L #
BB663011L #
BB663012L #
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts to solve this problem, try to search forums too  you may get more help here. Also give it sometime and then try to select any of the answer as correct answer to complete the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} {$0=($1 in a?a[$1]:$1" #")} 1' newport  panelport
```

If you don't want `#` in output then following may help.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} {$0=($1 in a?a[$1]:$1)} 1' newport  panelport
```

Comment: the `  #` concatenation part is not nice.

Comment: @Kent, I thought OP needed it, I will add solution without it too now.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1' newport  panelport
```